# Ошибка при компиляции приложения. Error: package okhttp3 does not exist import okhttp3.HttpUrl;

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javac

При попытке скомпилировать приложение командой 'javac' в консоли, получаю ошибки при компиляции

```
MainParser.java:1: error: package okhttp3 does not exist
import okhttp3.HttpUrl;
              ^
MainParser.java:2: error: package okhttp3 does not exist
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
              ^
MainParser.java:3: error: package okhttp3 does not exist
import okhttp3.Request;
```

Для работы использую IntelliJ IDEA.

Зависимости были добавлены через Maven. Добавил через Gradle - И всё равно получаю ошибки такие.

В коде импорт библиотек присутствует:

```
import okhttp3.HttpUrl;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
```

Использую библиотеку в методе:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(HttpUrl.get("http://mysite.ru/"))
        .build();

        Response httpResponse = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
}
```

С чем это связано? Вот что пишет консоль:

```
C:\Users\Skipper\IdeaProjects\untitled\src\main\java>javac MainParser.java
MainParser.java:1: error: package okhttp3 does not exist
import okhttp3.HttpUrl;
              ^
MainParser.java:2: error: package okhttp3 does not exist
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
              ^
MainParser.java:3: error: package okhttp3 does not exist
import okhttp3.Request;
              ^
MainParser.java:4: error: package okhttp3 does not exist
import okhttp3.Response;
              ^
```

**P.S:** при этом всё билдится и запускается и работает , если запускать через IntelliJ IDEA кнопкой **Run**

Comment: а при чем тут javac ? компиляцию вызывайте мавеном или гредлом

Comment: а запустить потом как?

Comment: если запуск из IDEA, в ней есть Run configuration - мастер, в котором можно создать конфигурацию для запуска конкретного приложения